# Get data from HTML key-value

Tags: html, swift, key-value

I would like to get the key value from HTML.
Presently using swift soup to get the element by index.
If the website element index changes, I am unable to get the value.
Want to retrieve the value based on the key
Below sample HTML:

```
<table class="Tbl"><tbody><tr><td colspan="4" style="background-color:#D49F3E"><div class="Val" style="text-align:center;color:#540000">Saturday, December 30, 2017</div></td></tr><tr><td style="width:18%"><div class="Key">Sunrise:</div></td><td style="width:32%"><div class="Val">06:30</div></td><td style="width:18%"><div class="Key">Sunset:</div> </td><td style="width:32%"><div class="Val">17:52</div></td></tr>
```

My present code is

```
do{
   let htmlContent = html
    do{
        let doc =  try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlContent as String)
        do{
            let element = try doc.select("[class=Val]").array()
            do{
                let today = try element[0].text()
                let Sunrise = try element[1].text()
                print(today)
                print(Sunrise)
            }catch{
            }
        }catch{
        }
    }catch{
    }
}
```

Please advice how to get the valve by key

EDIT-1:
Tried to apply. Below the code and getting error. Any Suggestions?

```
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url! as URL)
        let html = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!

        do{
            let html1: String = html as String
            let els: Elements = try SwiftSoup.parse(html1).getElementsByClass("Tbl")
            for keyVal: Element in els.array(){
                let keyValText: String = try keyVal.text()
                print(keyValText)
                let components = keyValText
                    .components(separatedBy: .newlines)
                    .filter{
                        !$0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty
                }
                if let index = components.index(where: {$0.contains(find: "Sunrise")}){
                    let sunriseTest = components[components.index(after: index)] //Error : Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
                    print("sunriseTest: ", sunriseTest)
                }else{

                }
            }

        }catch Exception.Error(let type, let message){
            print(message)
        }catch{
            print("error")
        }
```

Comment: you can just convert your html to string `"Saturday, December 30, 2017\nSunrise:\n06:30\nSunset:\n17:52\n"` and get the components separated by newLines

Comment: Can you post an example of how your html string would look like if the "index changes"?

Comment: Sample html, if index changes     `<table class="Tbl"><tbody><tr><td colspan="4" style="background-color:#D49F3E"><div class="Val" style="text-align:center;color:#540000">Saturday, December 30, 2017</div></td></tr><tr><td style="width:18%"><div class="Key">Sunrise:</div></td><td style="width:32%"><div class="Val">06:30</div></td><td style="width:18%"><div class="Key">&nbsp;</div></td><td style="width:32%"><div class="Val">&nbsp;</div></td><td style="width:18%"><div class="Key">Sunset:</div> </td><td style="width:32%"><div class="Val">17:52</div></td></tr>`

Answer (score 0):

you can just convert your html to string and get the components separated by newLines. to fix the index problem just filter the lines that are empty after trimming whiteSpaces:

```
struct Sun {
    let date: String
    let sunset: String
    let sunrise: String
    init?(string: String) {
        guard string.count > 4 else { return nil }
        let components = string
            .components(separatedBy: .newlines)
            .filter {
                !$0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty
        }
        date = components[0]
        sunset = components[2]
        sunrise = components[4]
    }
    init?(data: Data) throws {
        self.init(string: try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil).string)
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let html1 = """
<table class="Tbl"><tbody><tr><td colspan="4" style="background-color:#D49F3E"><div class="Val" style="text-align:center;color:#540000">Saturday, December 30, 2017</div></td></tr><tr><td style="width:18%"><div class="Key">Sunrise:</div></td><td style="width:32%"><div class="Val">06:30</div></td><td style="width:18%"><div class="Key">Sunset:</div> </td><td style="width:32%"><div class="Val">17:52</div></td></tr>
"""
let html2 = """
<table class="Tbl"><tbody><tr><td colspan="4" style="background-color:#D49F3E"><div class="Val" style="text-align:center;color:#540000">Saturday, December 30, 2017</div></td></tr><tr><td style="width:18%"><div class="Key">Sunrise:</div></td><td style="width:32%"><div class="Val">06:30</div></td><td style="width:18%"><div class="Key">&nbsp;</div></td><td style="width:32%"><div class="Val">&nbsp;</div></td><td style="width:18%"><div class="Key">Sunset:</div> </td><td style="width:32%"><div class="Val">17:52</div></td></tr>
"""
```

---

```
do {
    if let sun = try Sun(data: Data(html2.utf8)) {
        print("Today:", sun.date)
        print("Sunset:", sun.sunset)
        print("Sunrise:",sun.sunrise)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

> Today: Saturday, December 30, 2017 Sunset: 06:30 Sunrise: 17:52

Comment: I will make a try. One doubt. Will it get the value for the key even if the index order changes?

Comment: It will set the properties in the order you provide in the initializer. If you think that sunset might come after sunrise better to try to find the index of the word Sunset and get the next line

Comment: `if let index = components.index(where: {$0.contains("Sunset")}) {
                sunset = components[components.index(after: index)]
            } else { return nil }
            if let index = components.index(where: {$0.contains("Sunrise")}) {
                sunrise = components[components.index(after: index)]
            } else { return nil }`